# Node JS Installation on CentOS using Root Login

Tags: centos, root, non-root-user, cpanel

I have installed node js( using sudo yum install nodejs) on centos 7 using root which seems find as root user but not accessible for other users.

When I check as root user I am able to see version
root@server.com [~]# node -v
v16.14.2
[image: root shell screenshot]

But for non root user its
nonrootuser@server.com [~]# node -v
node: error while loading shared libraries: libbrotlidec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[image: non root shell screenshot]

Comment: `I have installed node js` what method did you use to install nodejs

Comment: i have used - sudo yum install nodejs @jaromanda-x

Comment: I am no expert on this, but it seems like non-root users cannot find the shared object file for `brotli` on your system. Maybe try `sudo yum install brotli`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked- thanks